# Creating an Ubuntu boot disk with specific kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, intel-nuc

Is there a way to create a custom boot disk from USB with a specific kernel from Windows 10?

I'm a beginner at this, and I have an Intel NUC7CJYH on which I want to install Ubuntu. I've tried different versions of Ubuntu (16.04.5, 17.10, 17.10.1, 18.04.1) with no luck. It freezes within minutes after/during installing via USB (no external cd/dvd drive available). The hardware should be supported (https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201802-26090/), but it apparently needs a specific kernel to run, which I don't know how to handle.

I'm primarily a Windows user, so if there's something like UCK but for Windows, that would be the best. If needed, I have an extra laptop around that I could use (I hope) as a staging ground with an Ubuntu live USB drive.

Comment: have you tried adding nomodeset to your boot line? see this post: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 and scroll down to "How to enable kernel options on the livecd (before install)" follow those directions and add `nomodeset` at the end of the boot line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ISO image for NUC7CJYH is available from this page: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-nuc-desktop.

It is a custom 16.04 ISO, with some installation steps.